# QPrintDialog localization

Tags: c++, qt, localization

How to localize QPrintDialog? I've tried to use /usr/share/qt4/translations/qt_ru.qm but it only translates word "Cancel" and the rest of dialog remains in English.

Comment: Print dialog seems to use native OS dialog, so it use OS language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to download an updated version of qt_ru.ts from [here](http://chaos.troll.no/~buddenha/qt-l10n/). And convert it to qm by running `lrelease qt_ru.ts`.

**update**

I believe this is what the result should be:
[image]

This ts file is the one from the link I posted originally